# How to count filled text box in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have six text boxes and I want to count the number of filled boxes

```
<input type="text" #tb1 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb2)" />
<input type="text" #tb2 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb2)" />
<input type="text" #tb3 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb3)" />
<input type="text" #tb4 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb4)" />
<input type="text" #tb5 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb5)" />
<input type="text" #tb6 placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"(ngModelChange)="counterfunc(tb6)" />

{{counter}}

counter: number = 0;

counterfunc(tb){
    // need help here
    if (tb.value != '') {
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

I found this plunker [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7IscAC60rSwrkVSSVnm?p=preview) but this is for checkboxes. how can I count the number of the filled text boxes? and a number of counts should decrease one if user empty the box. Thank you

Comment: Look at your plunker, replace checkbox per text. So look how the plunker works and do same, basically you have to look each input if they are empty or not (empty = -1, not empty = +1)

Comment: You can wrap your inputs in form and use form value object to check the number of values it has...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of declaring seleveral variables for a component (well, input) that behaves exactly the same in any case. You should declare a list of inputs, not a variable for every input.

Use the children decorator for that

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">  
  <input type="text" #textboxes placeholder="Weight" class="form-control" (input)="input()"/>
</ng-container>

<p>{{filledCount}}</p>
```

In your TS

```
filledCount: number = 0;
@ViewChildren('textboxes') textboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;
input() { this.filledCount = this.textboxes.filter(t => t.nativeElement.value).length; }
```

Here is a **[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq8a6i?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this and just take this as a key

```
counter: number = 0;

counterfunc(tb){
    if (tb.value != '' && tb.value.length == 1) {
       this.counter++;
     }
    if(tb.value == '')
     {
       this.counter--;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form and add validation to the form. On every change count the valid or invalid fields